# Knockout error confusion relating to remove function

Tags: knockout.js

I have a knockout model with observable arrays, trying to call the remove function but saying that 'remove' is undefined.  Here is one that works:

```
this.reportGroups.remove(function (item) { return item.fieldId == data.fieldId });
```

And here is the one giving the error:

```
this.reportFields.remove(function (item) { return item.FieldId == data.FieldId });
```

They are both observableArrays, it does contain items, I checked that the value passed is valid and contains FieldId etc so I'm not sure how to debug further?

EDIT:

Model that goes in array:

```
function FieldItem(FieldId, TableId, GroupId, PositionInGroup, FieldName, FieldType, FriendlyName, Description, QueryNumber) {
        return {
            FieldId: FieldId,
            TableId: TableId,
            GroupId: GroupId,
            PositionInGroup: PositionInGroup,
            FieldName: FieldName,
            FieldType: FieldType,
            FriendlyName: FriendlyName,
            Description: Description,
            QueryNumber: QueryNumber
        };
    }
```

They are added by pushing to reportFields observableArray, and remove function called like so:

```
<!-- ko foreach: reportFields -->
<tr>
   <td><span data-bind="text: FriendlyName"></span></td>
   <td><img src="SystemImages/cross.png" data-bind="click: $parent.removeField" /></td>
</tr>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Can you post some more context? Like the definition of your properties on the KO model and the method where you try to call `this.reportFields.remove` ?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that reportFields' type has been changed to something other than observableArray in some where in your codes.
Give it a try to change code like this

```
this.reportFields().remove( ..... )
```

If that works, it is certain that reportFields is not observableArray

Comment: this then changes error to being unable to find method reportFields() so should be observableArray

Comment: can you elaborate more about the code that push the elements to reportFields?

Comment: Ajax Call gets class of same properties (showing success part only):

    `success: function (result) {
       var fld = result.d;
       fld.QueryNumber = "0";
       model.reportFields.push(fld);
    },`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by moving the remove function out of the model itself i.e. instead of having this.reportFields.remove(etc) within the function of the knockout model I called an external function and changed it to model.reportFields.remove(etc)

I think because the objects were pushed using model. externally that I have to do the same for other related functions for it.